# spacy NER model: behind the scene

Tags: python, spacy

The documentation with the algorithm used for training a NER model in spacy is not yet implemented. The only information provided is:

- that both the tagger, parser and entity recognizer(NER) using linear model with weights learned using the averaged perceptron algorithm.
- conjuction features out of atomic predictors are used to train the model.

These info are taken from: [spacy-training-doc](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/training)

Now, I have a trained a model with a new entity type(lets say `animal`) and reasonable high number of examples (>10000). Now trying some examples in the trained model I have:

```
input text: "cat is an animal" => cat: animal
input text: "tv is an animal" => tv: O
```

If average perceptron is used to evaluate a word as an entity shouldn't these two examples give the same results?(`cat:animal, tv:animal`) or is something that I am confused?

From my understanding the algorithm is using “gazetteer” features (lookup of
entity names in a pre-compiled list created by the provided examples). If this is the case is there any way to exclude gazetteer features?

Any insights would be usefull.

Comment: spaCy NER does not use a linear model. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381170/which-deep-learning-algorithm-does-spacy-uses-when-we-train-custom-model/60394246#60394246) on what it does under the hood.

Comment: Regarding the gazetteer, the NER model (for example in `en_core_web_lg`) does not contain a gazetteer. You can add one yourself, see this post: https://support.prodi.gy/t/ner-with-gazetteer/272

Comment: The question is too old and *is* answered in the current spaCy documentation

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov if old questions would be closed cause they are 'old' then SO would have 1% of the current questions/answers.